# sbt Could not find launcher jar: ./bin/sbt-launch.jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I have been using sbt successfully for basic Scala compiling for several years, but the other day it just quit working for some reason. I was using it in my own account, but I decided to have my sysadmin install the latest version on our local network. When I try to run it, I get

Could not find launcher jar: ./bin/sbt-launch.jar

The launcher jar file is right there in the bin directory, and I am baffled as to why it is not found. I even tried the -sbt-jar option, but that did not help. I also tried renaming my old .sbt configuration directory (to disable it in case it was somehow interfering with the new installation), but that didn't help either. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out -- with some help from tech support. When I removed all of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH elements from my .bashrc file, it worked again. Lots of junk had accumulated there over the years.