# sbt : Could not find launcher jar: ./bin/sbt-launch.jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I downloaded sbt-1.2.6.zip for use on Linux. I unzipped it and went to the bin dir and typed sbt. I get this error:

```
Could not find launcher jar: ./bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

That file is sitting in the same directory as sbt.

I have been told at the [sbt support page](https://www.scala-sbt.org/support.html):

"For community support please ask on StackOverflow with the tag "sbt".

> Note: [the other question for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769321/sbt-could-not-find-launcher-jar-bin-sbt-launch-jar) has an answer of "removed all
>   the LD_LIBRARY_PATH elements from my .bashrc file". Not sure that
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used in finding jar files, and my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is
>   empty, not "filled with junk".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be only with the path to your `sbt` and launcher jar. You don't need to touch `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

First of all many linux distros and Mac OSX (`brew`) let you install sbt directly from package manager like `apt`, `dnf`, `yum`, etc. without manual download. If your distro has it available and the version is up to date, you can use one command to install it.

If that fails or you want to install manually there are multiple options. What you need to understand is that `SBT` is a shell runner script which in turn calls the jar file.

One way to install would be to use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Downloads the latest version of SBT runner script which in turn downloads
# SBT launcher JAR and provides lots of convenience methods.

curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > sbt && chmod 0755 sbt
```

Download from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izmailoff/scala-ml/master/get_sbt.sh).

Another option is like you did is to unzip everything to some `bin` directory for example. If that `bin` directory is in your `PATH` then typing `sbt` should work, if it's not, then you have to `cd` into that directory and type `./sbt`.

From the error you are getting **you should be in directory above**, i.e. `cd ..`. That's because it's looking for `bin` directory in your current directory: `./bin/sbt-launch.jar`. Although you can also change that path in the script to give it full path or path relative to your home dir, so it always works, you probably don't have to do it if `sbt` is on your path.

In the end you want to make sure that `sbt` script is on your `PATH` because you want to run this command from your project directory. Start with that and post if you have any errors.

Comment: being in the "sbt" main directory and typing bin/sbt works, as does puting $HOME/sbt/bin in the PATH. (there is both a directory and a shell script named sbt). I am using the Pixelbook Linux which uses Debian packages and it doesn't appear that they have an sbt package. May try that curl command.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `brew` to install `sbt`, then the `sbt-launch.jar` is located at the following location

```
➜  ~ ls /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.4.7/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.4.7/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

If you had used `brew` to install a specific version of `sbt`, like I did, then it is located in a folder like below -

```
➜  ~ ls /usr/local/Cellar/sbt@0.13/0.13.18_1/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt@0.13/0.13.18_1/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

As you can see, the `sbt-launch.jar` is installed in the `<sbt-home>/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar` folder.

If you had installed `sbt` manually, and now forgot the folder in which `sbt` is installed, then you can list the folder by the following command -

```
➜  ~ which sbt
sbt: aliased to /usr/local/Cellar/sbt@0.13/0.13.18_1/bin/sbt
```